# Admin login substantially slower on production server

Tags: plugins, php, wp-admin

The admin login on my production server takes upwards of 30 seconds to log in, which isn't acceptable. I assume this is probably a plugin issue, but I didn't want to start turning plugins on and off on a live site, so I made a clone of the site on my development server.

I'd expected the development server to be a little faster, but it's almost instant, despite having the same database and code exactly.

The site itself works fine on the production server, no speed issues, and the admin section is perfectly fine *once* you're logged in, but that initial login is a killer.

The only different between the production and development server is that the development server is running a more up to date version of PHP. Could that make that huge of a difference? We have other websites running on the same version of PHP that aren't having this issue.

Comment: possible Brute Force Attacks on login page. Check here https://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks

Comment: Wouldn't that also affect the speed of the website generally?

Comment: Its attack wp-login.php page mostly.